# Binary data utility class

Tags: c++, file, io

I have recently been trying to get a solid grasp of how to work with binary data, both for networking and file storage, in C++. In java, there are many utility classes that made this easy. Since these don't exist in C++, I figured making a limited class that does something similar would be a good way to learn how to work with binary data.

BinaryBlob.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned char byte;

class BinaryBlob{
public:
    void loadFromFile(const std::string &filePath);
    void writeToFile(const std::string &filePath) const;

    void writeBool(bool b);
    bool readBool();

    void writeInt(int b);
    int readInt();

    void writeString(const std::string &str);
    std::string readString();

    void writeBytes(byte *data, unsigned length);
    inline void readBytes(byte *data, unsigned length); //inline so that it is inlined with the other read functions, irrelevant to non-member functions since those won't be inlined in separate implementation files
private:
    std::vector<byte> m_binaryData;
    unsigned m_readIndex = 0;

    constexpr static unsigned BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
};
```

BinaryBlob.cpp:

```
#include "BinaryBlob.h"

#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>

void BinaryBlob::loadFromFile(const std::string &filePath){
    std::ifstream fin(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    byte buffer[1024];

    while(fin){
        fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), BUFFER_SIZE);
        writeBytes(buffer, fin.gcount());
    }
}

void BinaryBlob::writeToFile(const std::string &filePath) const {
    std::ofstream fout(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m_binaryData.data()), m_binaryData.size());
}

void BinaryBlob::writeBool(bool b) {
    byte byteData = b ? 1 : 0l;
    writeBytes(&byteData, 1);
}

bool BinaryBlob::readBool(){
    byte byteData;
    readBytes(&byteData, 1);
    return byteData == 1;
}

void BinaryBlob::writeInt(int b){
    std::uint32_t absValue = std::abs(b);
    bool isPositive = b > 0;
    writeBool(isPositive);
    writeBytes(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&absValue), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
}

int BinaryBlob::readInt(){
    bool isPositive = readBool();
    std::uint32_t absValue;
    readBytes(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&absValue), sizeof(std::uint32_t));
    return absValue * (isPositive ? 1 : -1);
}

void BinaryBlob::writeString(const std::string &str) {
    writeInt(str.length()); //I know this would probably be better as an unsigned value, but because this is a simple practice, no method to write unsigned values is created
    for(unsigned i=0;i<str.length();++i){
        char c = str[i];
        writeBytes(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&c), 1);
    }
}

std::string BinaryBlob::readString() {
    int length = readInt();

    std::string str;
    str.reserve(length);

    char *characterData = new char[length];

    readBytes(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(characterData), length);

    for(unsigned i=0;i<length;++i){
        str.push_back(characterData[i]);
    }

    delete characterData;

    return str;
}

void BinaryBlob::writeBytes(byte *data, unsigned length){
    for(unsigned i=0;i<length;++i){
        m_binaryData.push_back(data[i]);
    }
}

void BinaryBlob::readBytes(byte *data, unsigned length){
    for(unsigned i=0;i<length;++i){
        data[i] = m_binaryData[m_readIndex+i];
    }
    m_readIndex += length;
}
```

Test program 1 (designed to test if the file io functions work):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "BinaryBlob.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <input-file> <output-file>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string inputPath = argv[1];
    std::string outputPath = argv[2];
    BinaryBlob binaryBlob;

    binaryBlob.loadFromFile(inputPath);
    binaryBlob.writeToFile(outputPath);

    return 0;
}
```

Test program 2 (designed to test if the type <-> binary data functions work):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "BinaryBlob.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <file> <create/read>" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::string file = argv[1];
    std::string command = argv[2];

    BinaryBlob binaryBlob;
    bool b;
    int i;
    std::string str;

    if(command == "create"){
        std::cout << "Enter a boolean: ";
        std::cin >> b;

        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> i;

        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::cin >> str;

        binaryBlob.writeBool(b);
        binaryBlob.writeInt(i);
        binaryBlob.writeString(str);
        binaryBlob.writeToFile(file);
    }else if(command == "read"){
        binaryBlob.loadFromFile(file);

        b = binaryBlob.readBool();
        i = binaryBlob.readInt();
        str = binaryBlob.readString();

        std::cout << "Boolean is: " << b << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Integer is: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "String is: " << str << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The specific things I am interested in feedback on are (although any other feedback of any sort is most certainly welcome, as long as it's remotely useful):

- Because I only have access to a handful of Intel and AMD cpus, which are all very similar, I didn't test this code for portability (ie. running on an ARM CPU), to see if files generated on one CPU are readable on the other. Ignoring endianness, is there anything I missed?
- If I am writing code designed to be run on x86 CPUs only (both Intel and AMD), but with a variety of compilers and OSes, do I need to worry about anything more than I did here (including endianness)?
- Is my use of `reinterpret_cast` correct?
- For the string writing, I am just casting the string's data to its byte representation. Is this reliable? I know the C++ standard does not guarantee a character encoding, but do these encodings differ in practice on x86 CPUs? What about on broader ranges (ie. ARM?). Does this depend on the compiler or OS? If I wanted to correctly handle this, such that it is fully portable, how would I do so?
- How far, if at all, am I jumping outside the C++ standard with this code, into undefined behavior? Unless this is "not at all," how can I accomplish the same thing fully within the standard? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice Question.

I would hesitate to port the code as it is currently implemented.

**For Portability Don't Ignore Warnings**
When the library will be distributed on multiple platforms it might be better to use the -Werror flag to make
all warnings into errors. Any warnings may become errors on other architectures. At a minimum when compiling for
a portable library the [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) flag should be used.

Using Xcode on El Capitan (Mac OSX) I got multiple warnings about integer versus long mismatch. It might be better to change the length parameter in these functions to take `size_t` rather than unsigned int:

```
    void writeBytes(byte *data, unsigned length);
    inline void readBytes(byte *data, unsigned length);
    void writeInt(int b);
```

A common practice these days is to make all array indexes `size_t` for example [std::string::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) is defined using `size_t`.

**Inconsistent Use of Constants**
In the function `BinaryBlob::loadFromFile(const std::string &filePath)` The buffer size is 1024 while the read uses the defined constant `BUFFER_SIZE`, it would be best to define buffer in terms of `BUFFER_SIZE` as well.

It might be best to use a system defined constant for the buffer size to improve performance. Some systems may have a 4K, 8K or 16K file buffer size. Reading the file system block size and then processing the block with in the program will definitely improve performance.

**Inline**
The inline [keyword is now only a recommendation](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/) and the compiler might ignore it. An optimizing compiler may inline every one of these functions as well.

**Deleting an Allocated Array**
In std::string BinaryBlob::readString() the line

```
    delete characterData;
```

is not doing what you think it should be doing, it would be best to change this to

```
    delete [] characterData;
```

to delete the entire array.

**Testing Everything in One Shot**
By moving the code within the two different mains into functions both tests could have been completed in  one test run. Tests should always be repeatable, and they may not be repeatable using command line input.

It might be good to check out open source test frameworks. One such test framework for C++ is [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html).

**Style and Readability**
All of the for loops are compressed

```
    for(unsigned i=0;i<str.length();++i){
```

It is generally more acceptable to put spaces between symbols to make it more readable:

```
    for(unsigned i=0; i < str.length(); ++i){
```